# Add a value to an array contained in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

Please how to add a new element to an array which is a value of a dictionary?

When I try to add the element like this:

```
res[key].append(newelement)
```

it just erases the previous value.

My complete code looks like

```
        data = [{"signal_name": "X", "signal_value": "valueX1"},
                {"signal_name": "Y", "signal_value": "valueY1"},
                {"signal_name": "Z", "signal_value": "valueZ1"},
                {"signal_name": "X", "signal_value": "valueX2"}]

        res = {}
        for i in data:
            for k, v in i.items():
                if k == "signal_name":
                    res[v] = []
                    temp = v
                if k == "signal_value":
                    res[temp].append(v)
```

my output looks like this

```
Reading from input
{'X': ['valueX1']}
{'X': ['valueX1'], 'Y': ['valueY1']}
{'X': ['valueX1'], 'Y': ['valueY1'], 'Z': ['valueZ1']}
{'X': ['valueX2'], 'Y': ['valueY1'], 'Z': ['valueZ1']}
Done reading
```

so the X value is updated rather than contains the ['valueX1', 'valueX2']

Comment: you should try with `.update()` function of **dict** in python, that would create a copy of updated **dict**

Comment: `res[temp].append(v)` works well. In `res[v] = []` line, you are assigning an empty list when you encounter `X` second time and ever time you encounter again.

Comment: Thanks @Alperen, you are right. i just added a condition, and now it works well

Comment: @Reims Glad to hear. Take look at the answer that I posted. I think, it will give you another perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`res[temp].append(v)` works well. In `res[v] = []` line, you are assigning an empty list when you encounter `X` second time and ever time you encounter again.

I recommend you to use [dictionary `get()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get).

```
res = {}
for d in data:
    key = d["signal_name"]
    value = d["signal_value"]

    l = res.get(key, []) # Return [] if key is not in the dictonary
    l.append(value)
    res[key] = l

print(res)
```

Output:

```
{'X': ['valueX1', 'valueX2'], 'Y': ['valueY1'], 'Z': ['valueZ1']}
```

Comment: Hey, 
any idea if i want to add a third parameter? like time, but want to align firs all the values, and then the time?

something  output llike

{'X': ['valueX1', 'valueX2', ..., 'valueXN', 'timeX1', 'timeX2', ..., 'timeXN',], 'Y': ['valueY1'], 'Z': ['valueZ1']} ?

Comment: I guess, you mean if there is "signal_time" in the dictionaries of data. You can use list of lists or tuple of lists. Add a line as `time = d["signal_time"]` and change these lines:`l = res.get(key, ([], []))`, `l[0].append(value)` and `l[1].append(time)`. At the end you will have an output as `{'X': (['valueX1', 'valueX2', ..., 'valueXN'],[ 'timeX1', 'timeX2', ..., 'timeXN'])`

Comment: yes, that is what i mean , just that the valueX, and timeX should be in the same array, just that all the valueX come first, and then the corresponding timeX. like {'X': (['valueX1', 'valueX2', ..., 'valueXN', 'timeX1', 'timeX2', ..., 'timeXN']) i will probably do a concatenation of this two array?

Comment: Yes, you can concatenate these two lists at the end. Otherwise, I can't see an efficient way to maintain them in one list.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, Hope this will help:

```
data = [{"signal_name": "X", "signal_value": "valueX1"},
                {"signal_name": "Y", "signal_value": "valueY1"},
                {"signal_name": "Z", "signal_value": "valueZ1"},
                {"signal_name": "X", "signal_value": "valueX2"}]

res = {}
for i in data:
    temp = None
    for k, v in i.items():
        if k == "signal_name":
            try:
                res[v]
            except:
                res[v]=[]   #<-- As everytime you were initializing it, this was the error 
            temp = v
        if k == "signal_value":
            print(temp)
            print(res[temp])
            res[temp].append(v)
```

Ouput will be :

```
{'X': ['valueX1', 'valueX2'], 'Y': ['valueY1'], 'Z': ['valueZ1']}
```

Comment: @Reims, if it work for you, please upvote my answer